# CarrierWave use one uploader two times in single model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, carrierwave

I have a model called `User`. It has two fields: `small_logo` and `big_logo`. 
Those are actually **different** pictures, not just one resized picture.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
    mount_uploader :big_logo, UserLogoUploader
    mount_uploader :small_logo, UserLogoUploader
  ...
end
```

I use `UserLogoUploader` to upload this pictures.

And I'm running onto a bug - as long as the name of the model is the same, uploaded files get the same route, so if I try to upload two different files with same names - second one overwrites first one.

The obvious solution is to use different uploaders for those fields. But I don't want to create another uploader just to fix this bug - is there anything I can do to modify filename, for example, with something meaningful like the name of a formfield that submitted this file or access name of a model field that is being processed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an answer to my own question after some searching

There is a `mounted_as` attribute inside an uploader, which, reffering to docs, does exactly what I need:

```
If a model is given as the first parameter, it will stored in the uploader, and
available throught +#model+. Likewise, mounted_as stores the name of the column
where this instance of the uploader is mounted. These values can then be used inside
your uploader.
```

So the whole solution looks like this:

```
def UserLogoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  ...
  def store_dir
    File.join [
      Settings.carrierwave.store_dir_prefix,
      model.class.to_s.underscore,
      mounted_as.to_s,
      model.id.to_s
    ].select(&:present?)
  end
  ...
end
```

This code creates different subfolders for different model fields, which helps preventing names duplication and files overwriting.